# Start Apache despite error in Virtual Host's SSL certificate file

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have Apache 2.4.10 with name based SSL (SNI) virtual hosting.
Virtual users can use their own certificate and upload it to server.

Everything works fine until there is some error with certificate file (i.e. file is missing or with wrong name).

Problem is Apache will not start if there is some certificate problem.

Is there some solution how to start Apache with this error (i.e. all vhosts will start except that one virtual host with failure)?

This does not work:

```
<If "-f '/path/to/file.crt'">
    <VritualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</If>
```

...and this also does not work:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <If "-f '/path/to/file.crt'">
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
    </If>
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is syntax error in configuration "SSLEngine not allowed here" or "VirtualHost not allowed here". So my config above is not allowed by Apache.

Many thanks.

Edit: Small Typo

Comment: if you post apache error from your /var/log/apache2/error.log, maybe it can be helpfull

Comment: Can you try enclosing the file name in single quotes?

Comment: Sorry for delay and thanks for response.
Problem is syntax error in configuration "SSLEngine not allowed here" or "VirtualHost not allowed here".
So my config above is not allowed by Apache.

Comment: 2 piit79: yes, without single quotes there is another error, my fault, but the main problem is SSLEngine nor VirtualHost directives are not allowed inside If directive. So I am finding another solution.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution, @Otak? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not yet @Ravan Maybe the only solution is what JinnFox wrote, even it is not what I am looking for. On my server I implemented Letsencrypt and this is only certificate it supports. And it works for all :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say, this is working by design.
SSL certificates are a security feature. Why would you allow broken certificates on your system, which can compromise the whole server?

As you mentioned, that users can upload their certificates, you need to implement a check feature of those certificates. The validity, correct spelling and integrity of those files should be checked by your upload feature after all.

Additionally, apache is shipping a configuration checker.

```
$SERVER/bin/apachectl configtest
```

With this feature, you can check your config files before restarting, if there is any error, you should not restart your server.

Comment: Thanks for great answer with another point of view. 
But: every user has its own second level domain and all domains are totaly different virtual servers (Apache virtual servers), so I hope i.e. self-signed certificate will not compromise the whole server (maybe this one domain which is under control of that user). So all I want is to enable SSL support only if user upload their certificate (and I hoped there is some better solution then some workaround script). Configtest is good idea but not the solution in case of server power failure, sw upgrade or another reason for restarting it.

Comment: You can reject those certificates, which are failing your configtest. Then you're safe on both sides.

Comment: yes, but this is the solution aka "homemade workaround script", which is of course possible in any case. I try to find some "systematic" solution in apache config (i.e. 500 Internal server error but not config syntax error). Maybe little script "cert-checker.sh" (check cert files and change apache config files for those domains with problems) is quicker solution that what i am looking for...

Comment: But your solution already uploads those files. Why not implement a check there? Otherwise wrong config is still wrong config. You need to check this. There is no workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to start apache in a broken state, you should think of a way to validate the SSLs that are being uploaded by your users, and only if they are valid, to be applied in your apache config.

Example, if the following two MD5 outputs match, cert is (at least) valid (could be self signed, but still valid):

```
openssl x509 –noout –modulus –in <file>.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa –noout –modulus –in <file>.key | openssl md5
```

Comment: ..this is what @JinnFox already said, question was not about some workaround (which works of course), but if there exists some "better" solution in Apache config (i.e. 500 Internal server error for specified domain, but not config error for whole server).